# Bit Manipulation for DNA file Convert

Tags: java, scala, stream, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am building a program in Scala that converts DNA data stored in txt files using 8 bits per a  Char to a file using 2 bits per a Char. The only Chars that DNA uses are T,C,A,G. I want to use 2 bits for each char where T = 00, C = 01, A = 10, and G = 11. I want this to be as compact as possible without any wasted bits.

Right now, I am writing out 8 bits per a Char instead of the two I want to use. For the outPut method, can you suggest any bit manipulation I can do to maximize space and only use two bits per a char?

Comment: Who's the idiot who keeps downvoting posts and running away without comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to output less than a byte at a time. You will have to build an 8-bit char out of the 2-bit dna letters before writing out a char.

I don't know Scala or Java, but in a combination of your code and something more like C it would go like this:

```
  def outPut(in: DataInputStream, out: DataOutputStream) {
    var result = getChars(in)

    int letter_count = 0       // whatever a plain old integer is called
    char byte = 0

    for(i <- 0 until result.length) {

      if (result(i) == "A") {
        byte = (byte << 2) | 2         // move byte over 2 bits and "or" in new bits
      }else if(result(i) == "T") {
        byte = (byte << 2) | 0         // the "| 0" part here actually does nothing
      }else if(result(i) == "C") {
        byte = (byte << 2) | 1
      }else {
        byte = (byte << 2) | 3
      }

      letter_count += 1

      if (letter_count == 4) {
        out.writeByte(byte)
        letter_count = 0
        byte = 0
      }

   }
  }
```

Note user3580294's answer as well.

To go in the other direction (from 2-bit encoding to character encoding) :

```
  def toLetter(x) {
    if (x == 0)
      return "T"
    else if (x == 1)
      return "C"
    else if (x == 2)
      return "A"
    else if (x == 3)
      return "G"
  }

  def outputLetters(in: DataInputStream, out: DataOutputStream) {
    var twobit = getChars(in)   // or however you read the file

    for(i <- 0 until twobit.length) {
      byte = twobit(i)
      out.writeByte(toLetter((byte >> 6) & 3))
      out.writeByte(toLetter((byte >> 4) & 3))
      out.writeByte(toLetter((byte >> 2) & 3))
      out.writeByte(toLetter( byte       & 3))
    }
  }
```

This essentially assumes that the number of letters is evenly divisible by 4. To overcome that limitation, you'd need to store an extra piece of information in the file. It could either be the number of letters in the last byte (1 to 4), or the total number of letters represented in the file (from which the number of letters in the last byte can be calculated).

Comment: Thank you. So if I wanted to go from 2bit to txt any idea how I could do that?

Comment: @user3335040 I've added another section to the answer. You'll have to fix it up to make it proper Scala, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only write out whole bytes at once, sounds like me you'll have to read letters in groups of 4 and use some bit-shifting to be able to use all 8 bits per byte. This could cause some issues though if the number of letters isn't a multiple of 4 because you won't have a way of distinguishing padding from normal letters...

(sorry, I don't know Scala, but this algorithm should work independent of language)

So something like

```
// Store byte equivalents of ATCG in variables, or use an enum
// create new byte[4]
// Fill array with next 4 chars, ideally using something like Java's InputStream.read(byte[] b) so you can read in groups
// create temp byte variable
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    switch(b) {
        case <byte equivalent of A>:
            temp += <binary equivalent of A> << 3 - i;
// Repeat for other letters
// Write out temp
```

Comment: He could also store the total letter count.

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit more scala-ish. Group the bases in fours (possibly less for the last one) and map each sequence of up to four chars to the appropriate values.

```
def makeBits(base:Char):Int = {
        base match {
        case 'T' => 0
        case 'C' => 1
        case 'A' => 2
        case 'G' => 3
        case _ =>   -1 // some error here
    }
}  

def packBits(bases:String):Int = {
    var res:Int = 0
    for (bits <- bases) { res = (res << 2) + makeBits(bits)}
    res
}                           
val packed = "ATGCTTTADGCA".grouped(4).map(packBits)
```